# 'function' object has no attribute 'objects' DJANGO(ERROR GETTING DATA FROM DATABASE)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get data from the database sqllite and fetch the data n print it in the html file(user1.html) . I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEcXbeY4_DQ) line by line.

So this is my **models.py** file in the app called **mainpage**

```
from django.db import models

class user1(models.Model):
  id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
  maths=models.IntegerField()
  physics=models.IntegerField()
  english=models.IntegerField()
  computer=models.IntegerField()

  def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

This is my urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.conf.urls.static import static
 from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [

   url(r'^user1/', 'mainpage.views.user1',name='user1'),
   url(r'^user2z/', 'mainpage.views.user2z',name='user2z'),
  ]
```

This is my view.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
 from .models import *
 from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
 from django.template.response import TemplateResponse


 def user1(request):
    return render(request, "user1.html",{})



 def user2z(request):
   data=user1.objects.all()
   return TemplateResponse(request,"user1.html",{"data":data})
```

This is my user1.html file

```
   hello check
    {{ data }}
    {% for video in data  %}
      <h1>{{ video.id }}</h1>
      <h1>I m ideot</h1>
    {% endfor  %}
    <br>
    hell check
    <br>
```

so when i do `localhost:8000/user2z` i get the following error:

```
AttributeError at /user2z/
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
 Request Method:    GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/user2z/
Django Version: 1.9.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'function' object has no attribute 'objects'
Exception Location:        C:\Users\vaibhav2\PycharmProjects\MyUniversityResult\mainpage\views.py in user2z, line 16
 Python Executable: C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\vaibhav2\\PycharmProjects\\MyUniversityResult',
'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python34\\lib',
'C:\\Python34',
'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 30 Oct 2016 20:00:58 +0530
  Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

 C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)      ...
 ▶ Local vars
 C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args,        **callback_kwargs) ...
  ▶ Local vars
  C:\Users\vaibhav2\PycharmProjects\MyUniversityResult\mainpage\views.py in  user2z
   data=user1.objects.all() ...
   ▼ Local vars
  Variable  Value
 request    
 <WSGIRequest: GET '/user2z/'>
```

Please tell me if you are able to spot any error in it. It would be awesome if you could point me to any tutorial that explains how to get data from database. Videos would be preferred.

Comment: "trying 2 get"? Not 3 get or 4 get?

Comment: typing error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
 def user1(request):
```

means there's a function `user1` in scope that overrides the model class so that `user1.objects` can't work. Name the function something else or write:

```
import .models
...
data = models.user1.objects.all()
```

Comment: I have removed these 2 lines from my views.py(commented them up)==   #def user1(request):
  #   return render(request, "user1.html",{})   //Still the same error when localhost:8000/user2z

Comment: @InfiniTy did you restart the server? Or, what if you try the second suggestion?

Comment: i did it obviously

Comment: i have changed my model name completely . U were right there was aa name conflict between model named user1 nd fuction named user1.  I DON'T KNOW HOW 2 THANK U .THANK U SO MUCH SIR